# Pytesseract : File missing when trying to use Image_to_Boxes() API

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

**[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tess_3gyrbu0d_out.box'**

I am getting this error when I am trying to use Image_to_Boxes() API.
Image_to_String() is working without any error.
Thanks in Advance !!!!

Comment: How much available space do you have in /tmp directory?